# Using Value from Promise inside Angular Observable Interceptor

Tags: angular, promise, observable, angular7, ionic4

I am trying to use a JWT interceptor service to authenticate every call the user makes to an API for a Ionic 4 app.
I have a JWT interceptor that looks like so

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    let token = 'THE_JWT_HERE'
    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

This works statically to add the token to the correct header to the request. However, I need to get the user's actual JWT from Ionic storage, which is promised based.

I thought it might look something like this:

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    this.authenticationService.getJWT()
      .then(token => {
      if (token) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        });
      }
    return next.handle(request);
  })
  }
}
```

This breaks at compile because I am returning a promise, instead of an observable.
However, if I place `return next.handle(request)` outside the promise, no Authorization header is being added. I understand why this is occurring, but I am unsure of the solution.

How can I access this value from a promise and use it inside of this interceptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use some rxjs -- one method might be to switchMap:

```
import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators"; 
import { from as observableFrom } from "rxjs";

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return observableFrom(this.authenticationService.getJWT())
    .pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        if (token) {
          request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
          });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    ); 
}
```

essentially, you want to get that promise converted to an observable and merge it into an observable chain resulting in the `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` that the intercept is supposed to return.

the next logical question is, is there any way for you to cache the authenticationService request, and simply use that cached value in requests?  i'd suggest an accessor pattern in a service that looks up the token the first time it's requested and simply returns the result thereafter.  it'll slow your requests down significantly if you're doing an authenticationService request ahead of every single HttpRequest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Derelict. I believe the pattern you requested is exactly what I'm looking for. I am now getting an error that Property switchMap exist on type Observable<Promise<any>>. Any idea how to solve?

As to the second question, the getJWT() method retrives the JWT from ionic storage. The ionic storage library is promise based though, hence my issue.

Comment: I had to use .pipe before switchMap, and token is evaluating to a promise.

Comment: sorry, i think you want `import { from as observableFrom }` apologize for typing unchecked code off the top of my head.  to convert the promise you need 'from' not 'of' -- edited answer to reflect these changes

Comment: That did it! Thanks a ton.